# Not able to pass array of data to chart.js in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am trying to pass array of data fetched from JSON data to **labels** and **data** in charts.js as following to plot a **Bar Chart**:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios'
import Chart from './Chart'
class CaseList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             posts: [] 

        }
    }

componentWillMount() {

      const {posts} = this.state
        var states=[]
        var num=[]

        for (var i=1;i<posts.length;i+=1) {
          states[i-1]=posts[i].state
          num[i-1]=posts[i].confirmed
      }

        this.getchartData(states,num);

    }

getchartData(states,num){
this.setState({
        chartData:{
          labels: states,
        datasets: [
          {
            label:'No. of Positive Cases',
            data:num,
            backgroundColor:[

              'rgba(255,3,0,1)',
              'rgba(219,3,0,1)',
              'rgba(152,3,0,1)',
              'rgba(255,3,0,0.7)',
              'rgba(101,191,217,1)',
              'rgba(101,191,217,0.59)',
              'rgba(101,79,161,0.98)',
              'rgba(208,79,197,0.98)',
              'rgba(208,79,197,0.65)',
              'rgba(43,144,197,1)',
              ]
          }
        ]
      }
      })
    }

componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get('https://api.covid19india.org/data.json')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({posts:response.data.statewise})
            })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

render(){
return(
<div>
<Chart chartData={this.state.chartData} />
</div>
  )
}
}
```

Where Chart is another .js file as follows:-

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';

class Chart extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chartData:props.chartData
    }
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    displayTitle:true,
    displayLegend: true,
    legendPosition:'right',
    location:'City'
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="chart">
        <Bar
          data={this.state.chartData}
          options={{
            title:{
              display:this.props.displayTitle,
              text:'State-Wise Bar Chart',
              fontSize:25
            },
            legend:{
              display:this.props.displayLegend,
              position:this.props.legendPosition
            }
          }}
        />
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

JSON Data looks something like this:-

```
[
        {
            "active": "23648",
            "confirmed": "33184",
            "deaths": "1081",
            "deltaconfirmed": "122",
            "deltadeaths": "2",
            "deltarecovered": "18",
            "lastupdatedtime": "30/04/2020 09:52:45",
            "recovered": "8455",
            "state": "Total",
            "statecode": "TT",
            "statenotes": ""
        },
        {
            "active": "7890",
            "confirmed": "9915",
            "deaths": "432",
            "deltaconfirmed": "0",
            "deltadeaths": "0",
            "deltarecovered": "0",
            "lastupdatedtime": "29/04/2020 22:37:46",
            "recovered": "1593",
            "state": "Maharashtra",
            "statecode": "MH",
            "statenotes": ""
        },
        {
            "active": "3358",
            "confirmed": "4082",
            "deaths": "197",
            "deltaconfirmed": "0",
            "deltadeaths": "0",
            "deltarecovered": "0",
            "lastupdatedtime": "29/04/2020 20:54:45",
            "recovered": "527",
            "state": "Gujarat",
            "statecode": "GJ",
            "statenotes": ""
        },
        {
            "active": "2291",
            "confirmed": "3439",
            "deaths": "56",
            "deltaconfirmed": "0",
            "deltadeaths": "0",
            "deltarecovered": "0",
            "lastupdatedtime": "29/04/2020 23:16:45",
            "recovered": "1092",
            "state": "Delhi",
            "statecode": "DL",
            "statenotes": ""
        },
        {
            "active": "1969",
            "confirmed": "2560",
            "deaths": "130",
            "deltaconfirmed": "0",
            "deltadeaths": "0",
            "deltarecovered": "0",
            "lastupdatedtime": "29/04/2020 21:02:47",
            "recovered": "461",
            "state": "Madhya Pradesh",
            "statecode": "MP",
            "statenotes": ""
        }
]
```

But this returns an array of size 0 for both states and num in `componentWillMount()` and `getchartData()` functions. I tried by manually entering all the enteries in **labels** and **data** and it works. Can anyone suggest how to pass the array data properly?

Comment: where is your fetch request?

Comment: @SachinKammar I have edited the question and added the fetch request. Hope this helps

Comment: There is no need to use state in the chart component. Why don't you use the passed props directly?

Comment: if your chart is going to change with some parameters like date or something, you need to have it in a state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of componentWillMount you can add posts in componentDidMount.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Axios from 'axios';
import {Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';
class Chart extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chartData:props.chartData || {}
    }
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    displayTitle:true,
    displayLegend: true,
    legendPosition:'right',
    location:'City'
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="chart">
        <Bar
          data={this.state.chartData}
          options={{
            title:{
              display:this.props.displayTitle,
              text:'State-Wise Bar Chart',
              fontSize:25
            },
            legend:{
              display:this.props.displayLegend,
              position:this.props.legendPosition
            }
          }}
        />
        </div>
    )
  }
}

class CaseList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             posts: [] ,
             chartData:{}
        }
    }

getchartData(states,num){
  console.log("states",states,"num",num)
this.setState({
        chartData:{
          labels: states,
        datasets: [
          {
            label:'No. of Positive Cases',
            data:num,
            backgroundColor:[

              'rgba(255,3,0,1)',
              'rgba(219,3,0,1)',
              'rgba(152,3,0,1)',
              'rgba(255,3,0,0.7)',
              'rgba(101,191,217,1)',
              'rgba(101,191,217,0.59)',
              'rgba(101,79,161,0.98)',
              'rgba(208,79,197,0.98)',
              'rgba(208,79,197,0.65)',
              'rgba(43,144,197,1)',
              ]
          }
        ]
      }
      },()=>{console.log(this.state.chartData)})
    }

componentDidMount() {
        Axios.get('https://api.covid19india.org/data.json')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({posts:response.data.statewise});
            const posts = response.data.statewise
            var states=[]
            var num=[]

            for (var i=1;i<posts.length;i+=1) {
              states[i-1]=posts[i].state
              num[i-1]=posts[i].confirmed
          }
          this.getchartData(states,num);
            })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

render(){
return(
<div>
{Object.keys(this.state.chartData).length>0 &&<Chart chartData={this.state.chartData} />}
</div>
  )
}
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
    <CaseList />,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: check this working codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-fast-otn8y